What' the intuition behind Shankar's postulate II?
In Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics (second edition), P115, he lists some postulates of quantum mechanics. In specific, he mentions a postulate which is list below:

II. The independent variables $x$ and $p$ of classical mechanics are represented by Hermitian operators $X$ and $P$ with the following matrix elements in the eigenbasis of $X$.
$$\langle x|X|x' \rangle = x \delta(x-x')$$
$$\langle x|P|x' \rangle = -i\hslash\ \delta^\prime(x-x')$$The operators corresponding
dependent variables given Hermitian operators$^{\S}$
$$\Omega(X, P) = \omega(x \rightarrow X, p \rightarrow P).$$

Well, at first glance, I thought it's about probability theory. When you have two random variable, you can calculate the expectations of some functions of random variables using LOTUS. But then I realized that, it may be not about expectation, it's about operator. Because you can calculate the eigenvalue of the combined operator, which I think should be the function of eigenvalues of original operator. Also Shankar mentions in his Chapter 1, you can substitute operator to functions of one variable, as soon as it's can be written in power series. But with function of two variable, could we do that? What's the exact mathematic behind it?
I want to ask the physics reason of it, too. How can we rationalize the postulate?
SECOND EDIT: I don't like "you don't need to rationalize postulates". It then seems like the postulate comes from nowhere, just from someone's imagination, which happens to be correct.

Please don't post screnshots/images of text and equations. Rather, type the relevant passage (using MathJax).

You should ask what is the reason. Intuition is something very different and not very reliable in physics.

"IF SOMEONE IMAGINE IT, IT MUST HAVE A PROCESS, IN WHICH IT COMES FROM." First, why are you SCREAMING? Second, this screamed sentence makes no sense.

@BioPhysicist I'm sorry if you feel upset. I think it's my fault not to leave a notice at the beginning in my thread.I intended to do so but I   forgot .Until your answer reminded me of that .Again I'm sorry but my words are not aimed at you

@hft I'm not native speaker .I just want to stress something .I'll correct it thank you.

In classical physics the evolution of the position and momentum of a particle are described by functions $x(t),p(t)$ whose values are the value you would get if you measured the position and momentum at time $t$.
In quantum theory the evolution of a measurable quantity such as the position or momentum of a particle is described by a Hermitean operator called an observable whose eigenvalues are the possible results of a measurement of that quantity which can undergo quantum interference. For an example, see Section 2 of
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
The expectation value of the observable $\hat{A}(t)$ is $\langle\hat{A}(t)\rangle=tr(\rho\hat{A}(t))$ where $\rho$ is an operator with unit trace called the density operator or the state.
The rough idea behind the procedure described by Shankar is that you replace positions and momenta in classical equations of motion and measurable quantities with position and momentum observables to get the relevant quantum equations of motion and observables: this is called quantisation.
There are restrictions on when this procedure can be carried out:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0304202

I don't know if it's the intuition, but here's one way in which one could arrive at the postulate.
When you are first introduced to quantum mechanics, you usually don't work in an abstract Hilbert space. Instead, you work on a specific space of functions: the possible wave functions of, say, an electron. These are functions $\psi:S\to\mathbb C$, where $S$ is the physical space in which our experiment happens. In a simple case, $S=\mathbb R^3$.
You will then take note that an electron has a specific momentum if it has a harmonic wave function. Specifically, if $\psi(x,t)=e^{\mathrm i(kx-\omega t)}$, then it has momentum $p=\hbar k$. But also note that taking the derivative $\partial_x\psi$ yields $\mathrm ik\psi$. That's proportional to $p\psi$. To make it equal to $p\psi$, we'd have to multiply by $\frac{\hbar}{\mathrm i}=-\mathrm i\hbar$. So $-\mathrm i\hbar\partial_x\psi=p\psi$. If the electron has a definite momentum.
But also note that the same works for energy with $\mathrm i\hbar\partial_t$ if the electron has a definite energy.
And if we Fourier transform in the position variable, the same works for position with $\mathrm i\hbar\partial_p$ if the electron has a definite position.
So all three of the fundamental mechanical observables can be recovered from the wave function by applying a differential operator, and those are linear. So it's a reasonable question to ask: Is this true for other observables? And experiments confirm that yes, it is true. And it turns out that these operators allow elegant descriptions of the physics, for instance allowing very efficient calculations of expected values of observables.

You don't rationalize postulates. Postulates are the "starting point", and the rest of the theory builds from them. Then we test the validity of the set of postulates and the theory by looking at experiments and the world around us. If the theory agrees with reality, we assume the postulates lead to a good model of reality. If there is a mismatch, then it shows you need to tweak the postulates.
In quantum mechanics, it has been found that representing observables as linear operators that can act on vectors of a linear vector space representing the state of a quantum system can lead to accurate descriptions of reality (the rest of the postulates are needed to give the full picture). Postulate II is defining the operators associated with position and momentum, and what they look like in the position basis. But this is a starting assumption; it is not proved from anything deeper. It happens to work, so that is what we do.
